# Extract new dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, I would like to create a new dictionary where the first key `'value'` corresponds to the second value of the `'b'` key of each dictionary in the list. The second key `'number'` of the new dictionary corresponds to the third (therefore last) value of the `'b'` key of each dictionary in the list.

```
my_list = [
    {
        'a': (2.6, 0.08, 47.0, 1),
        'b': (5.7, 0.05, 1)
    },
    {
        'a': (2.6, 0.08, 47.0, 2),
        'b': (5.7, 0.06, 2)
    }
]
```

expected output:

```
new_dic = {'value': (0.05, 0.06), number = (1, 2)}
```

Comment: Alright. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use comprehension as follows:

```
new_dict = {}
new_dict['value'] = tuple(val['b'][1] for val in my_list)
new_dict['number'] = tuple(val['b'][2] for val in my_list)
```

Note that you need to call the tuple constructor, because `(val['b'][2] for val in my_list)` alone returns a generator object.